# Fine surface in PGFPlots to mark invalid area

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I have the following plot:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
      use comma,
      view={0}{90},
      x tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1, /tikz/.cd},
      y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, fixed zerofill, precision=1, /tikz/.cd},
      xmin=-5,
      xmax=5,
      ymin=-5,
      ymax=5,
      zmin=-80,
      zmax=250,
      minor x tick num=1,
      minor y tick num=1,
      major tick style={draw=black},
      xlabel=$x_1$,
      ylabel=$x_2$,
      zlabel={~},
      xtick={-5, -4, ..., 5},
      ytick={-5, -4, ..., 5},
      zticklabels={,,},
      width=15cm,
      height=13cm]
    \addplot3 [surf, color=light_gray, samples=30, restrict z to domain=0:100, shader=flat] {((x-2)^2+(y-2)^2)-1};
    \addplot3 [contour gnuplot = {labels=false, number=30}, thick, colormap/RdBu] table {data/styblinski_tang.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Bla.}
  \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}
```

The figure shows a [test function](https://www.sfu.ca/%7Essurjano/stybtang.html) overlaid by a quadratic function (as defined in the code). I want to depict, that the area in which this function is negative is a "valid" area, the rest should be "invalid". Therefore I draw the function without the negative z domain. This works basically well, but as soon as I increase the samples, I get an error regarding memory size, and in the current diagram it is way to coarse. What would be a good way to implement this? I also tried to implement it with *contour filled* but it didn't work either.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could maybe use the polar transformation of the function to plot the valid area using something like `\addplot [draw=none, fill=white, samples=100] ({sin(deg(x))+2}, {cos(deg(x))+2});`. Add `axis background/.style={fill=light_gray}` to the axis envrionment to shade everything else gray.